# iOS MDM - Making Managed settings permanent

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-provisioning, mdm

As per the "Mobile Device Management Protocol" API document from Apple, I am trying to restrict access to Data Roaming on iOS devices connected to my MDM server.

I can toggle the Data Roaming setting by sending the appropriate Settings request, however the user can then toggle Data Roaming straight back on.

This is addressed in Apple's documentation with the following paragraph :

> In iOS 5 or later, this command allows the server to set settings on the device. These settings take effect on a one-time basis. The user may still be able to change the settings at a later time. This command requires the Apply Settings right.

The "might" suggests to me that there should be a way to restrict this, but I can not find a complete list of Global Restrictions that might solve this problem.

Is there a way to remove access to either the "Data Roaming" settings option, or even disable access to the whole "Settings->General->Cellular" sub menu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.

I checked the document with configuration profiles:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef.pdf

Also, I checked iPhone configuration utility.

None of them has Data Roaming restriction.

So, the only thing available is that MDM Settings which you are using already.

Comment: I can not find a way either, however I know it must be possible as other implementations of MDM support this. Unless the reason they require an additional application to be installed is because applications can override this setting while MDM can not.

Comment: @DavidT: Who supports it? Did you actually try their solution? It could be just a marketing fluff.

Comment: AirWatch's system does it, but obviously they aren't sharing source, and I can't figure out how they are achieving the result.